# Socket.io - Cannot emit to a specific room but can emit to everyone

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using `Socket.io 2.0.4` and `React.js (CRA)`

**Background:** In my server code (server.js) once someone sucessfully joins a room I want to emit an event that tells all clients in that room that someone joined.

**Problem:** I don't get an error but nothing get's transmitted to my client if I try to use `.to(room)` or `.in(room)` in conjuction with `.emit`... but `.emit` will work on it's own.

**What Works:** I am successfully able to implement to the `socket.join()` code and in the callback I console.log the IDs of each person that's joined using the `showClients` function I created. I can see each person join one at a time via console.

**Notes:** I store the room name in the data variable and access it using `data.room` but I've also just wrote in the room name manually to no avail.

**Client Code (abridged)**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Card from '../card/card';
import './game.css';

const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io()  

class Game extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super();
    }

componentDidMount(){
        this.gameCode();
        this.cardSelected();

        socket.on("cardDiscarded", this.updateDiscard);

        socket.on("playerJoined", () => {
            alert("hi!");
            console.log("YAY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        });
    }
   //....rest of my code....
}
```

**Server Code (abridged)**

*Look at the `joinRoom` function to see the issue*

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

console.log("Hello world!");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {

    socket.on("createNewRoom", (name) =>{
        CreateNewRoom();
        console.log("NEW ROOM CREATED!");
    })

    socket.on("joinRoomRequest", (name, room) =>{
        // console.log(name, room);
        console.log("Request to join room");
        var data = {
            name: name,
            room: room
        };
        joinRoom(data);
    })


    function CreateNewRoom() {
        //Get unique room number
        var thisGameId = (Math.random() * 1000000 ) | 0;

        //Send the room number to the browser
        socket.emit('newRoomCreated', {roomID: thisGameId, mySocketID: socket.id});
        //Tell socket.io this user is joining this room
        socket.join(thisGameId.toString());
        console.log(thisGameId);
    };

    function joinRoom(data){
        console.log("trying to join room:" + data.room);
        data.socketID = socket.id;
        console.log(data);
        socket.join(data.room, () => {
            let rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms);
            //Let the clients know a player has joined
            console.log(rooms);
            console.log(data.name + " JOINED room " + data.room);
            showClients(data.room);
            io.to(data.room).emit("playerJoined");  //<----- DOESN't WORK
        });
    }

    function showClients(room){
        var roomClients = io.of('/').in(room).clients((err, data)=>{
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("The people in room ", room, " are: ", data);
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Where are you emitting `createNewRoom`?

Comment: In another react component on the client side. It then successfully creates the room because `newRoomCreated` emit is picked up by the client.

Comment: Where is `joinRoomRequest` called? If you are sure everything is setup correctly and being hit I would say your `io.to` should read `io.sockets.in(roomName).emit('playerJoined', 'Some Data')`

Comment: In a seperate React component I emit the `joingRoomRequest` event when a user clicks the join button in the DOM.

`socket.emit("joinRoomRequest",guestName, room);`

Answer (score 4):

I believe `io.in(room).emit(data)` is what you are looking for. I recently ran into this problem as well. According to the documentation, if you want to emit to everyone accept 'socket' (aka the user who joined) you use `socket.to(room).emit`. If you want to emit to everyone including the user, you use `io.in(room).emit`

Comment: I've tried both and neither work. The problem seems that `.in` breaks the functionality or is unable to send it to the proper room even though I've tried sending it to `data.room` and `1234` and `"1234"` (Note: I like to use room 1234 in my tests)

Comment: I can use just `.emit()` or `.broadcast.emit()` to send it to everyone... but when I introduce the `.in(room)` then it breaks.

Comment: Does socket.to(room).emit work? Does anything using the room functionality work?

Comment: `socket.to(room).emit` does not work either. 

The only think that works is these lines...

`socket.join(data.room, () => {
            let rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms);
            console.log(rooms);});` which lists the room I created and the members.

Comment: I'm starting to think my socket.io isn't imported/setup properly. 

I can get `socket.to(room).emit` to work in my `<Lobby />` component but not my `<App>` or `<Game />` components

Comment: So it seems no room related things work except listing them. It's pretty odd. I'm not sure what's wrong. I guess make sure your rooms are strings? Try a string rather than 1234.

Comment: I tried adding `.toString()` to the end of `data.room` with no luck. It's got to be an issue with how I setup everything because I can get `socket.to(room).emit` to work when the receiving `.on` is in one component (js file) but not in the other two files (components) I tried... Also, something to note is that when it does work it only works with 2 users not when I introduce a third browser. When there are 3 browsers/windows one instance can only emit to the host not to the third instance and host.

Comment: I have a really similar problem here. I think it has to do with the socket Object on the client side. Something about it should be changing since the connection is basically in another room after a `join`. But in React the same instance gets used still... I supose that's why nothing room-related works. Did you solve this somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but I had the same problem. I have a Home page that helps user to create a private room. After that, user gets redirected to the Chat page. Both of these components create a socket connection by using "const io = socketIoClient(SOCKET_URL)". But  if I understand correctly, the socket which joined to the room is actually the socket on the Home page. So, I created a Provider component, created a single socket connection in it and used it at the root of application, passed the socket as Context value and used it in sub components. This way rooms work for me.

Comment: But I must say that, I'm a little new to using sockets and I'm not sure if it is a solid idea to using a singleton socket connection. I was using Firebase by using a structure like this. But, I'm not an expert on this stuff. My application is really small and I didn't bump into any issues for now.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve it like this:

does not work:

```
socket.join (my_room)
```

work:

```
socket.join (my_room.toString ())
```

Comment: You saved my day.

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for... i was using the id from mongodb as the room name, and even though it was listed in the rooms list, trying to send data to the room didnt work... only after making both the socket.join() and the io.to()... use toString() did it work, thanks

Comment: faced same... 
let roomName = "room_" + roomNumber.toString()  
worked for me

Comment: I'm using string as room ...its still not working